custom styling for Material Tooltip on Angular 17
I have an angular 17 app with latest Material components.
I am using the Tooltip component extensively and having problems finding how to customize it.
I did manage to change the font size using the following code in CSS:
$tt-typography: mat.define-typography-config(
    $caption: mat.define-typography-level(16px, 1, 400)
);

@include mat.tooltip-typography($tt-typography);

But this is only for font size and weight. I would also like to customize the line height, width of the tooltip and so on.
Can I do this with this code? If so, what more options can I set in it for these goals?
I should mention that I've already tried various CSS selectors that are supposed to override the defaults of Material (which is obviously the simplest and easiest way, if possible), but with no success so far.

The define-typography-level has the following definition in the source code
code change:
// `font-size`, `line-height`, `font-weight`, `font-family`, and `letter-spacing`.
$my-custom-typography-config: mat.define-typography-config(
  $caption:
    mat.define-typography-level(
      $font-size: 24px,
      $line-height: 24px,
      $font-weight: 400,
      $font-family: Helvetica,
      $letter-spacing: normal,
    ),
);

@include mat.tooltip-typography($my-custom-typography-config);

typography.md
## Typography levels

A **typography level** is a collection of typographic styles that corresponds to a specific
part of an application's structure, such as a header. Each level includes styles for font family,
font weight, font size, and letter spacing. Angular Material uses the [typography levels
from the 2018 version of the Material Design specification][2018-typography], outlined in the
table below.

| Name            | Description                                                  |
|-----------------|--------------------------------------------------------------|
| `headline-1`     | One-off header, usually at the top of the page (e.g. a hero header). |
| `headline-2`     | One-off header, usually at the top of the page (e.g. a hero header). |
| `headline-3`     | One-off header, usually at the top of the page (e.g. a hero header). |
| `headline-4`     | One-off header, usually at the top of the page (e.g. a hero header). |
| `headline-5`     | Section heading corresponding to the `<h1>` tag.             |
| `headline-6`     | Section heading corresponding to the `<h2>` tag.             |
| `subtitle-1`     | Section heading corresponding to the `<h3>` tag.             |
| `subtitle-2`     | Section heading corresponding to the `<h4>` tag.             |
| `body-1`         | Base body text.                                              |
| `body-2`         | Secondary body text.                                         |
| `caption`        | Smaller body and hint text.                                  |
| `button`         | Buttons and anchors.                                         |

[2018-typography]: https://m2.material.io/design/typography/the-type-system.html#type-scale

### Define a level

You can define a typography level with the `define-typography-level` Sass function. This function
accepts, in order, CSS values for `font-size`, `line-height`, `font-weight`, `font-family`, and
`letter-spacing`. You can also specify the parameters by name, as demonstrated in the example below.

```scss
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

$my-custom-level: mat.define-typography-level(
  $font-family: Roboto,
  $font-weight: 400,
  $font-size: 1rem,
  $line-height: 1,
  $letter-spacing: normal,
);
```

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks!! Is there a way of adding definitions to the original function of Material, outside of their css file? I mean, somehow via my app code, in order to be sure it's still there when the Material files get updated or changed for any reason.

@TheCuBeMan Its not recommended to modify the source code since it will go away when you update, its better to follow the same function and try to achieve what you need with it

That's what I mean, that I don't want to change the source code, for this exact reason. I'm asking if there is a way of manipulating this code "externally", via code from my own css files.

@TheCuBeMan I am not sure depends on the requirement, maybe ask a new question, someone might know, I am not aware sorry :(

$custom-typography: mat.define-typography-config(
  $caption: mat.define-typography-level(16px, 1.5, 400) 
);

@include mat.tooltip-typography($custom-typography);

::ng-deep .mat-tooltip {
  max-width: 200px; 
  line-height: 1.5; 
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px; 
  padding: 8px; 
}

